# Alternative to _input in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I recently ported a project from Visual Studio .NET 2003 to Visual Studio 2010. The problem here is that my code uses the built-in VC++7.1 _input. _input is used in a function which simulates the functionality of GNU glibc's vsscanf().

I realize that VS2010 provides _input_l as a replacement, however this function crashes consistently every time is called.

Is there any other replacement to this? What according to you is a recommended implementation of vsscanf() on Windows?

Comment: `_input` is an undocumented, internal CRT function.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: if _input_l is crashing regularly it's almost certainly an issue with how it's being called.  Can you post some sample code so we can help edtermine what's going wrong?

Comment: If you're in Visual C++, then get a std::stringstream. The scanf style functionalities have been deprecated for about a decade.

Comment: @DeadMG : I would rephrase into : "If you're in C++, then get a std::stringstream." :)

Comment: @DeadMG: What says they have been deprecated?

Comment: @Roger: Possibly the fact that a total replacement for them was written that's superior in virtually every possible way.